# How to numbering unique pairs X,Y

Tags: r, unique

Ok, so I have the following data.frame:

```
v1<-c(456,234,981,776,112,998)
v2<-c(981,112,456,998,234,776)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2)
```

I want to obtain an extra variable with a numeric count of pairs of v1 and v2 values. The trick is that I need to number them by unique pairs so, for example (456,981 and 981,456) should be numbered 1.

So the outcome would be something like this:

```
v1<-c(456,234,981,776,112,998)
v2<-c(981,112,456,998,234,776)
v3<-c(1,2,1,3,2,3)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this using dplyr. Basically you would sort the columns for each row. Not sure if it would be more efficient or not. Obviously it is a lot more lines.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(v1,v2)

# Sort by v1 and v2 elements by row
df.new <- df %>%
  mutate(z1 = pmin(v1,v2),
         z2 = pmax(v1,v2))

# Build a distinct coding table
df.codes <- df.new %>%
  distinct(z1, z2) %>%
  mutate(v3 = 1:n())

# Join it back together
df.new %>%
  left_join(df.codes, by = c("z1", "z2")) %>%
  select(v1, v2, v3)
```

Comment: Run some test! It seems that even having more lines is less computational demanding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! I know dplyr can be pretty efficient. Also there is the benefit of being able to operate on a data frame and maintaining the structure. I bet there is a way to do it with the related purrr package, but I have not played around with it much.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort rowwise and use `match`, i.e.

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, sort))))
match(v1, unique(v1))
#[1] 1 2 1 3 2 3
```

Comment: well, using `apply` is not the best thing since it coerces to matrix AND we need to transpose and convert back to data frame in order to paste.So I 'd say not very good but we can benchmark. Also I m not sure If there is another drastically more efficient way...

Comment: Yeah, when I saw (t(apply)) I started to think about the size of my matrix... I will try, and If I don't find a better solution I will qsub it to a cluster.